# OpenVPN - Cannot ping server computer from client

Tags: windows-7, openvpn, windows-10, ping

I am trying to get my OpenVPN setup working for our remote office.

I've installed the OpenVPN community to server and client, created the certificates. Port forwarding rules are also in place, and connection between client and server can be made without a glitch.

But when it comes to ping the client from the server or vice-versa, I got no luck.

I've tried to temporiarly disable firewall for both server and client, but no dice.

Both of the systems are running on Windows (7 on server, 10 on client). I'm using OpenVPN GUI v11.14.0.0.

Here are my slimmed down versions of config files:

Server:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Client:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxxx
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca "ca.crt"
cert "client.crt"
key "client.key"
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

If relevant, here is the active routing table on the client, listed while VPN is connected:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.43.1    192.168.43.64     50
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6    281
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.8.0.6    281
         10.8.0.6  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    281
         10.8.0.7  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.42.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.42.1    281
     192.168.42.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.42.1    281
   192.168.42.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.42.1    281
     192.168.43.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.43.64    306
    192.168.43.64  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.43.64    306
   192.168.43.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.43.64    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.6    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.42.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.43.64    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.42.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.43.64    306
===========================================================================
```

I feel that this is a problem of routing, but I have no clue about how to fix that.

UPDATE: Here is my interface information on the client

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e5fb:b1a6:a3ed:1715%23
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.42.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Unknown adapter Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c58:53c1:6455:38df%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Yerel Ağ Bağlantısı* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9da:bcc9:ee66:f9e4%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.23
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Ağ Bağlantısı:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

UPDATE 2: 
I've just noticed that if I try to ping the server (10.8.0.1), number of bytes out which is show on the OpenVPN GUI increases, as ping packages being sent.

Comment: Could you add information about IP addresses and interfaces on client?

Comment: Sure thing, just added it.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to ping both server's IP address on it's own local network, and it's IP addres within the VPN. I belive I should get response from both addresses, am I right to think that way?

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that your only routes down the tunnel are: 10.8.0.1/32 10.8.0.4/30 10.8.0.6/32 10.8.0.7/32. You'll need to add a default route and DNS servers, so something like this to your server congfig file:

```
push "redirect-gateway autolocal"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

after you've done this can you update question with  new config file and routing table from client

Comment: Can you please elaborate why are we pushing DNS clause to the client? Because we don't need to resolve any DNS, I'm trying to ping the server directly through IP address.

Comment: Ok I assumed you would want dns at some point down the tunnel but you will need the route in any case

Answer (score 0):

Windows may have recognized the new network as a 'Public' network.  If Windows Firewall is running it may not allow pings or file/print sharing across that network.

To check and fix that, you should go to Network and Sharing Center and click the Public icon in the middle of the network, and tell windows its a Work network.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little bit too late, but in my case, it worked by adding a route to the IPs I needed in the remote network since my PC was trying to reach them through the wrong gateways.

If you need to reach a 10.5.x.x on your remote network, you can try a tracert to that IP to see the route it is actually taking. If it is the case that it is trying to reach it through the Internet (or wrong gateway), try adding the following route on Powershell with Admin privileges:

route add 10.5.x.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1

i.e. 10.8.0.1 being the gateway assigned by your OpenVPN server, and 10.5.x.0 the subnet of the remote network you are trying to reach.

I hope this helps.